# Using pyodbc cause error: Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, odbc, pyodbc

I'm using pyodbc to connect SQL Server. I had created connection string like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, databases, Integer, String, ForeignKey, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import session
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://sa:123@localhost/TrainQuizDB')
engine.connect()
```

TrainQuizDB is database name that I created in Sql Server.

For more information I have windows 8.1 64bit and I installed python version 3.5.1 32bit and I downloaded pyodbc from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyodbc (pyodbc-3.0.10-cp35-none-win32.whl).
But when I try to connect it cause this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Also I have tested the connection In ODBC Data sources and it was successful.

[image: ODBC Connection]

Comment: Your screenshot indicates that the DSN you created was named `SQLO` but you included `TrainQuizDB` (the name of the SQL Server database, not the ODBC DSN) in your connection string. Try using a connection string with `SQLO` instead of `TrainQuizDB` and see if that works any better.

Comment: @GordThompson I create ODBC DSN just for test the connection. In the code I want to connect db directly. (server, db name, username, passwork)

Answer (score 3):

As noted in the [relevant section of the SQLAlchemy documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mssql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql.pyodbc):

> Hostname-based connections are not preferred, however are supported. The ODBC driver name must be explicitly specified

So, you need to add the driver name to your connection string:

```python
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://sa:123@localhost/TrainQuizDB?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server')
```