# Python Connect to mysql windows authentication

Tags: python, mysql

I am using the following syntax to connect to mysql db with windows authentication

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://[Server]/[db]')
```

However I got the following error:

```
DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Could you please help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37161574/using-pyodbc-cause-error-data-source-name-not-found-and-no-default-driver-speci