# How to push data from sheet excel file using pyodbc, to_sql, and sql server managment studio express r2 using windows authentication

Tags: python, pandas, pyodbc

I am trying to push data from excel file to sql_server express management studio 2008 using `pandas` and `pyodbc`, as I need to push data by creating a table in a database `myDB`

and here's my code

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import os

import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# connect db
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://WWX542337CDCD\SMARTRNO_EXPRESS/myDB?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0')
cursor = engine.raw_connection().cursor()


mydir = (os.getcwd()).replace('\\', '/') + '/'

lte_details = pd.read_excel(r'' + mydir + 'MNM_Rotterdam_5_Daily_Details-20191216081027.xlsx', sheet_name='LTE Details')

lte_details.columns = lte_details.columns.str.replace(' ', '')

# reading and insert one file at a time
for file in os.listdir('.'):
    # only process excels files
    file_basename, extension = file.split('.')
    if extension == 'xlsx':
        lte_details.to_sql(file_basename.lower(), con=engine.connect(), if_exists='replace')
```

and I find this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/mwx825326/PycharmProjects/MyReference/test.py", line 22, in <module>
    file_basename, extension = file.split('.')
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

and this is my connection
[image: connection sql]
Any one have any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: Did you try sqlalchemy engine? https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/faq/connections.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, you can try use to `sqlalchemy` connection. Because `con` in `pd.read_sql` uses `sqlalchemy engine`.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://**server**/**db**?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0')
cursor = engine.raw_connection().cursor()

lte_details.to_sql(file_basename.lower(), con=engine.connect(), if_exists='replace')
```

You can try this for split,

```py
file_basename, extension = tuple(file.split('.'))
```

Comment: thanks alot for your answer, but for my case I am using `windows authentication` no user name and password as when I tried to use your code I found this error `sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/rvf5)` please check edits, I am not using `SQL Authentication` here

Comment: Can you check this link? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37161574/using-pyodbc-cause-error-data-source-name-not-found-and-no-default-driver-speci I think you need to specify driver.

Comment: to be clear when I am connecting to server I an using `Server type` Database Engine, `Servername`, `Authentication` Windows Authentication like in the posted Picture, Check edits please

Comment: Can you try adding `.raw_connection()` to the end of the expression? Like this, `engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mssql://*server_name*\\SQLEXPRESS/*database_name*?trusted_connection=yes').raw_connection()`

Comment: it gave me the same error I got before, as I posted now :(

Comment: related to you edited answer I also face the same problem, this is due to because of the server name or some thing please could you check the attached picture?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204967/discussion-between-e-zeytinci-and-mahmoud-harooney).