# Why is my dataframe.to_sql throwing a DBAPI error?

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm attempting to insert data from a pandas dataframe into an MSSQL database table.

This is my code that's throwing an error

```
resultDf.to_sql(name='obscured',schema='dbo',if_exists='append', con=write_engine, index=True,chunksize=1500, method='multi')
```

This code worked/works

```
resultDf.head().to_sql(name='obscured',schema='dbo',if_exists='append', con=write_engine, index=True)
```

This is the error that I'm getting which according to sql alchemy's documentation is thrown by pyodbc, which is the driver I'm using for MSSQL.

```
DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('07002', '[07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')
[SQL: INSERT INTO dbo.obscured ([obscuredcolumn1], [obscuredcolumn2], [obscuredcolumn3], [obscuredcolumn4], [obscuredcolumn5], [obscuredcolumn6], [obscuredcolumn7], [obscuredcolumn8], [obscuredcolumn9]) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

there's probably 1500 or so tuples of ?, then 1500 or so tuples of actual values:

```
[parameters: (datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 9, 15, 0), 7179747, 868, 920, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 9, 15, 0), 7179748, 0, 430, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 9, 15, 0)
```

Where have I gone wrong? What should I be testing to troubleshoot?

Comment: Can you check if `resultDf` contains any empty strings `''` ? It seems that the `PYODBC` driver can't handle empty strings. Maybe the reason why you can push `resultDf.head()` to the MSSQL database table is that because the first five rows of  `resultDf`  doesn't carry any empty string.

Comment: All columns are cast as type ‘int32’

Comment: [Got a some solution regarding the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37161574/using-pyodbc-cause-error-data-source-name-not-found-and-no-default-driver-speci)

Comment: Follow this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37161574/using-pyodbc-cause-error-data-source-name-not-found-and-no-default-driver-speci

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's related to `chunksize`. I shrunk the `chunksize` from 1500 to 50, then gradually increased.
There must be a setting on the database side that's limiting the number of records that can be inserted at one time.